# How to select the same nodes without for-each in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following xml

```
    <phones>
      <phone>
        <code>+37529</code>
        <number>8546632</number>
      </phone>
      <phone>
        <code>+37517</code>
        <number>4562389</number>
      </phone>
   </phones>
```

I need to get the following html-table
[image]

Before that I had the next html-table

[image]

So my xsl file was like

```
<table>
...
   <xsl:for-each select="phones/phone">
      <tr>
         <td width="25%">Code</td>
         <td width="25%">
            <xsl:value-of select="code" />
            &#160;
         </td>
         <td width="25%">Number</td>
         <td width="25%">
            <xsl:value-of select="number" />
            &#160;
         </td>
      </tr>
   </xsl:for-each>
...
</table>
```

And now I should divide the phones and I don't know how to make xslt-transformation using the old xml file. Help me please build the right xsl-file. Thanks.

Comment: Are there always exactly two phone numbers? Is the second one always the mobile?

Comment: Actually the max phones numbers can be 3: Office, Mobile and Home. And one of them can be missed, or two, or all of them.

Comment: So how do you know which one is which?

Comment: Yes, you are right. If one phone is missed, I don't know which one is which. So I suppose my best solution will be to change my xml.

Comment: Indeed, you'll need something like `<phone type="office">`, `<phone type="mobile">` etc.

Answer (score 0):

The way I'd "select nodes without for-each" would be to use a template. For example:

### XML

Given the following XML (I took the liberty of adding `@type`'s, as per your comments):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<phones>
    <phone type="Office">
        <code>+37529</code>
        <number>8546632</number>
    </phone>
    <phone type="Mobile">
        <code>+37517</code>
        <number>4562389</number>
    </phone>
</phones>
```

### XSL

And the following XSL templates:

```
<xsl:template match="//phones">
    <table><xsl:apply-templates /></table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="phone">
    <tr>
        <th colspan='4'><xsl:value-of select="@type" />:</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Code</th><td><xsl:value-of select="code" /></td>
        <th>Number</th><td><xsl:value-of select="number" /></td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>
```

Gives the desired html table output. **E.g.** http://xsltransform.net/gWmuiJn/1

If you want to set the width of the tables (styling), I'd recommend using CSS instead of `width="25%"`. **E.g.** http://jsbin.com/woyaga/1/edit?html,css,output